# Why doesn't my MAMP server open my CodeIgniter controllers?

Tags: codeigniter, mamp

I've installed *MAMP* in my Mac (MacOS Sierra) and I created a Virtual Host. There I have a *CodeIgniter* project. But, when I try to open, for example, `localhost/project_name/contact/` my navigator give me this error:

**The requested url was not found on this server**

This doesn't happen when I open en main page.

How can I repair it?

Answer (score 2):

have you removed **index.php** using **.htaccess** already if not then try accessing using `localhost/project_name/index.php/contact/`

By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs:

```
example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article
```

If your Apache server has mod_rewrite enabled, you can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for existing directories and existing files is treated as a request for your index.php file.

Source :- [Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)